# MySQL INSTR - match exact substring

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a table with a column that stores data in the below fashion.

```
|  column1       |
+----------------+
|  [112,114]     |
|  [112,115]     |
|  [112,114]     |
|  []            |
|  [112]         |
|  []            |
|  [116]         |
|  [114,115,116] |
```

I want to be able to select records of that table where a record might have  1 or more of the comma separated numbers that are stored in the string of column1.

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('114', column1)
OR FIND_IN_SET('112', column1)
```

doesn't work here.

---

```
INSTR(d.villa_collections, "114") > 0
```

Works, but will also give me results if it's

```
INSTR(d.villa_collections, "11") > 0
```

How I should go about this in an efficient way that will allow me to match the desired records?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Do you have access to JSON functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use REGEXP:

```
WHERE column1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]123[[:>:]]'
```

It matches 123 if there is a word boundary before and after it.

```
SELECT '[112,114]' REGEXP '[[:<:]]112[[:>:]]'; -- 1
SELECT '[112,114]' REGEXP '[[:<:]]11[[:>:]]';  -- 0
SELECT '[112]'     REGEXP '[[:<:]]112[[:>:]]'; -- 1
SELECT '[11]'      REGEXP '[[:<:]]112[[:>:]]'; -- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) the square brackets and use `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('114', REPLACE(REPLACE(column1, '[', ''), ']', ''))
   OR FIND_IN_SET('112', REPLACE(REPLACE(column1, '[', ''), ']', ''))
```